# How to write a query to fetch data from DB on the basis of timestamp

Tags: sql, derby

I have a task to do in which i have to write a query which can fetch the data on the basis of timestamp

1. i have a table in my db having two columns one is `event` and other one is `Time`
2. what i am trying to do is to write a query which can give me data entered in last 1 minutes
3. I have written a query which is giving me correct result but in sql 5.1
4. i am using `Derby` data base and facing issue to get the output

[image: This is my database]

this is the error i am getting from running my query in derby

`error` `Syntax error: Encountered "5"`

my query is `SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE Time >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 5 minute
AND   Time <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the interval syntax, but you can try `TIMESTAMPADD()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE Time >= {fn TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MINUTE, -5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) }
AND Time <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: hey sir what is `SQL_TSI_MINUTE` as it is showing error

Comment: This: https://builds.apache.org/job/Derby-docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/out/ref/rrefjdbc88908.html

Comment: as i am very new to this not able to understand the eror this is the error i am getting error like this `Column 'SQL_TSI_MINUTE' is either not in any table in
the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is
outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a
HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a
CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'SQL_TSI_MINUTE' is not
a column in the target table`